# Can I use react native to build a app with another frontend?

Tags: android, react-native, frontend, apk

Sorry if there is already a similar question with answer and if there is, put the link here so I can reach it.

I'm having a difficuty these days...
I was told to create a new integration with a terminal called TERMINAL SMART G800 from GERTEC.
Here in the company we are usually use Cordova but it is deprecated and abandoned so I decided with my team to do this with React Native.

I started the project but I'm finding some difficulties and I can't find anything in Google...
The thing is, in the react native site, they have a tutorial to use react with an exsting andrid app but I didn't see nothing related to using react native to build an apk using an existing frontend project.
I mean, like if I wanted to use a responsive site, made with HTML and CSS to build an apk. But it seems that I need to use the react tools to do this. I'll need to recreate my app entirely.
Can someone help ?

FrontEnd structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzRJy.png)

React excample sructure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPPIb.png)

Comment: Why would you use react native without using the react native front end?  That's the entire point of react, it's a UI framework.  As for the doc on using RN in an android app-  that's meant for apps that want to use single RN screens or views in an otherwise android app, generally for testing the technology or slowly migrating from one to the other,.

Comment: If you want to just run a website as an android app-  write a small android app that has a WebView in it, loads your app from the apk, and displays it.  No need for react native.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see that :|.
That's a good idea. Do you know whether I can use WebView to create a integration with this terminal and control thee TEF and other hardware functionalities ?